# ByeBug is going too deep. Stepping into RubyCore files on 'next'

Tags: ruby, byebug

I am using "byebug" in a Ruby program.

As I "next" through the program "ByeBug" is going too deep and is steping into ruby/core.

This has never happened before. Is there a setting I can adjust to make it so ByeBug doesn't 'next' into the Ruby source and stays inside the program.

I call byebug with the following calls. Same results

> bundle exec rspec
>
> rspec
>
> ruby filename.rb